# Exporting composer with 2 maps in QGIS: wrong extent in one map after export

Tags: qgis, export, qgis-2.18

After creating this map in the QGIS 2.18.2 map composer 
[image: Layout in Map Composer]

(note that the red dot in the upper left map is shown in India),

I then export it to a PNG image file. However, the overview map in the upper right corner seems to have changed its extent and zoom during the export process, as the red dot is now located in Iran.

Any ideas why and how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: What is the CRS information you are using for you map?

Comment: The CRS of the map canvas in QGIS Desktop is set to WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator. This is probably defined by the Google Physical layer

Comment: The Polygons on the other hand are WGS84 / UTM zone 43N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the OpenLayers plugin it appears you are using. Use the QuickMapServices plugin instead, it's actively maintained and doesn't suffer the composer bugs that the OpenLayers plugin has.

Comment: This works, with the physical map. Do you know which plugin to use to access Google's VHR aerial images?